# Is it possible to calculate the mathematical function of a 2D image?

Tags: image, math, image-processing

The question basically says it all. I would like to add that lets suppose I have an image, a photograph and I wish to calculate its mathematical function, so that when I input x and y pixel value, it returns a vector consisting of R,G,B values at that x,y point. Therefore I can use a for loop to construct the whole image by just that function. I am not asking about the whole solution or algorithm here, but just that if this thing is possible, which direction should I take to go about doing this. Reference to relevant papers would be really nice.

Thanks
 Azmuh

Comment: The image **is** already a function; it provides a mapping from `{x,y}` to `{r,g,b}`.

Comment: Look at fractal image compression.

Comment: I know that image is itself a function but can you represent it in terms of a mathematical expression?

Comment: @azmuhak: It would be possible, for example, to find an *n*-th order 2D polynomial that interpolates all the pixel values.  But I'm not sure there would be a lot of point...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in general... Imagine an image that has been generated by random values for each pixel. You can't find a mathematical expression that will give you the value of a pixel given its 2d coordinates.

Now it may be possible for some images that have been generated using a function. In that case, it's not a problem specific to image processing, it's get back the function from some points of the function (in your case, you have all the points). It's exactly the same thing as extrapolating a curve from a set of points when you trace a graph in excel. The more points you have, the more precise the function you wind will be.

Look for information about Regression analysis. I can't help you much but there are some algorithms that exist.

Comment: Yes I think that in case of images which are mere repeated patterns, we can find out its function by geometry or trigonometry. But for non pattern images it is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is absolutely always possible. Basically, if you choose some points, there is always (an infinity of) smooth explicit functions (that is nice functions) which value on the points is exactly the one you choose.
For example, you can have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_interpolation. They are two different methods to compute an explicit function which pass exactly by the data points you have. So you can apply those methods for your image, seen as a set of data points, and separately for R, G, and B.

At the end, you get one simple function explicitly (a polynomial or a trigonometric series, depending on what you chose), and you can compute its values where you want.

However, note that *I would definitely **not** recommend to use those methods to effectively retrieve the data*. Indeed, the functions you get are absolutely not optimized (that is with a veeeery high degree (for a n×m image, each color will have a degree nm-1), very high coefficients) and furthermore will have extremely large values between your original points (look for Runge's phenomenon).